# beautifulsoup4 - how do I parse a specific class name?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

on site in tags like:

```
tr class="productBank tr-turn tr-link  row body odd" data-target="tr67" data-key="finservice"
```

or

```
tr class="productBank tr-turn tr-link  row body even"  data-target="tr420" data-key="runa-bank"
```

is stored info I want to parse, but also in that site there another tags like this:

```
tr class="productBank tr-turn tr-link curr_old row body odd" data-target="tr324" data-key="sov-bank"
```

or

```
tr class="productBank tr-turn tr-link curr_old row body even" data-target="tr64" data-key="morskoybank"
```

and if i try this:

```
items = soup.find_all('tr', class_='productBank')
```

it will return all king of tags content, but if i write name of the class all along there be empty list.

How can I access to that specific type of class?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you asking how to select multiple classes at once? You can use `class_="class-name1 class-name2"`.

Comment: I got a feeling you are mixing up the word "tag" and "attribute" or maybe "CSS class".

Answer (score 0):

It is all about finding the differences. In this case, you can find all tr elements with the 'productBank' class, then filter out the elements with the 'curr_old' class. The following code achieves this:

```
[e for e in soup.find_all('tr', {'class': ['productBank']}) if 'curr_old' not in e['class']]
```